# 2 scripts doesn't works together

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a script that generates a new image for me when the page is refreshed.

Now I would like to add a custom google map.

But the 2 don't work together, it's either one or the other depending on the order of the scripts.

https://paris.communauto.com/

Thank you for your help

I need your help !

On my homepage, i have

```js
//For google map


var latitudeCenter = "";
var longitudeCenter = "";
var lastOpenedInfoWindow = "";
var mapsGenerated = "";
var infoMap = [];
var zoneCoords = [];
var miniZoneCoords = [];
var trou = new Array();
var comp = 0;
var comp2 = 0;

var mapStyles = [
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
                "color": "#ffeb3b"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -35
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 35
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -55
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 30
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -90
            },
            {
                "lightness": 50
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 30
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -55
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -80
            },
            {
                "lightness": 25
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 25
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -65
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 75
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -25
            },
            {
                "lightness": 35
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -65
            },
            {
                "lightness": 40
            }
        ]
    }
];

function initialize() {

    for (var i = 0; i < mapsGenerated.length; i++) {
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            ajaxI: i,
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Branch/" + mapsGenerated[i][0] + "/AvailableCity?ReturnCitiesOfAssociatedBranches=true",
            contentType: 'application/xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            responseType: 'application/xml',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
            },

            success: function(xml) {

                i = this.ajaxI;
                comp++;

                jQuery(xml).find('BranchAvailableCityDTO').each(function() {
                    var branchIdXml = jQuery(this).find("BranchId").text();
                    var cityIdXml = jQuery(this).find("CityId").text();
                    if (mapsGenerated[i][1] == cityIdXml && mapsGenerated[i][0] == branchIdXml) {
                        latitudeCenter = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("CityCenterLocation").children().eq(0).text());
                        longitudeCenter = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("CityCenterLocation").children().eq(1).text());
                        infoMap.push({
                            id: i,
                            lat: latitudeCenter,
                            lng: longitudeCenter,
                            zoom: mapsGenerated[i][2],
                            branchId: mapsGenerated[i][0],
                            cityId: mapsGenerated[i][1]
                        });
                    }
                });

                if (comp == mapsGenerated.length) {

                    infoMap.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);
                    });

                    for (var i = 0; i < infoMap.length; i++) {
                        zoneCoords[i] = new Array();

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            ajaxI: i,
                            crossDomain: true,
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Zone?ZoneTypeId=1&BranchId=" + infoMap[i].branchId + "&CityId=" + infoMap[i].cityId + "&IncludeAssociatedCities=false",
                            contentType: 'application/xml',
                            dataType: 'xml',
                            responseType: 'application/xml',
                            headers: {
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
                            },
                            success: function(xml) {
                                i = this.ajaxI;
                                comp2++;
                                
                                jQuery(xml).find('ZoneDetailDTO').each(function(index) {
                                    
                                    zoneCoords[i][index] = new Array();
                                    
                                    if ( !( infoMap[i].cityId == 105 && index <= 1)  )  { 
                                        jQuery(this).find("Geometry").children("Coordinates").children("d4p1\\:ArrayOfDouble").each(function() {
                                            var latitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).children().eq(1).text());
                                            var longitude =  parseFloat(jQuery(this).children().eq(0).text());
                                            zoneCoords[i][index].push({
                                                index: index,
                                                id: i,
                                                city: infoMap[i].cityId,
                                                lat: latitude,
                                                lng: longitude
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                                

                                if (comp2 == infoMap.length) {
                                    
                                    infoMap.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0); });
    
                                    var maps = [];
                                    var infowindow = "";

                                    for (var i = 0; i < infoMap.length; i++) {

                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            ajaxI: i,
                                            crossDomain: true,
                                            type: 'GET',
                                            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Station?" + infoMap[i].branchId + "&CityId=" + infoMap[i].cityId,
                                            contentType: 'application/xml',
                                            dataType: 'xml',
                                            responseType: 'application/xml',
                                            headers: {
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
                                            },
                                            success: function(xml) {
                                                comp2++;
                                                i = this.ajaxI;
                                                
                                                var point = infoMap[i];
                                                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
                                                
                                                var mapOptions = {
                                                    center: latlng,
                                                    zoom: point.zoom,
                                                    minZoom: 8,
                                                    maxZoom: 16,
                                                    zoomControl: true,
                                                    mapTypeControl: false,
                                                    scaleControl: false,
                                                    streetViewControl: false,
                                                    rotateControl: false,
                                                    fullscreenControl: false,
                                                    styles: mapStyles,
                                                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                                };

                                                maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + (i + 1)), mapOptions);
                                                
                                                if (zoneCoords[i].length) {
                                                    
                                                    for (var y = 0; y < zoneCoords[i].length; y++) {
                                                        miniZoneCoords[y] = new Array();
                                                        trou[y] = new Array();
                                                        for (var z = 0; z < zoneCoords[i][y].length; z++) { 
                                                            miniZoneCoords[y][z] = new google.maps.LatLng( zoneCoords[i][y][z].lat, zoneCoords[i][y][z].lng );
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    var Zones = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                        paths: miniZoneCoords,
                                                        strokeColor: "#228BE6",
                                                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                                        strokeWeight: 2,
                                                        fillColor: "#228BE6",
                                                        fillOpacity: 0.15,
                                                    });
                                                    
                                                    Zones.setMap(maps[i]);
                                                    
                                                }
                                                
                                                jQuery(xml).find('StationDTO').each(function() {
                                                    var name = jQuery(this).find("StationName").text();
                                                    var stationNumber = jQuery(this).find("StationNb").text();
                                                    var latitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("Location").children(":first").text());
                                                    var longitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("Location").children().eq(1).text());
                                                    
                                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                        position: {
                                                            lat: latitude,
                                                            lng: longitude
                                                        },
                                                        map: maps[i],
                                                        icon: "https://www.communauto.com/lib/img/MAP/icon_vert.png"
                                                    });

                                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                                                        return function() {
                                                            closeLastOpenedInfoWindow();
                                                            var nom = 'Station ' + stationNumber;
                                                            infowindow.setContent('<span style="color:#8dc63f; font-weight:bold;">' + nom + '</span><br><span style="color:#4A5866;">' + name + '</span>');
                                                            infowindow.open(maps[i], marker);
                                                            lastOpenedInfoWindow = infowindow;
                                                        }
                                                    })(marker, infowindow));

                                                    function closeLastOpenedInfoWindow() {
                                                        if (lastOpenedInfoWindow) {
                                                            lastOpenedInfoWindow.close();
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(maps[i], "idle", function() {
                                                        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
                                                    });

                                                });

                                                maps[i].setCenter(mapOptions.center);
                                            }

                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }

            }

        })

    }

}


function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    // id de la branche
    // id de la ville
    // zoom voulu
    mapsGenerated = [
        [4, 96, 12]
    ];

    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing&' + 'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;


//for random image background

window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var pictures = new Array('https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-3.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-2.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-4.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-communauto-paris.webp');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
    }
}
```

```css
[id^=map] {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 0 1em; 
    width:100%; 
} 
[id^=map] a { 
  text-decoration:none;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column-legend-map {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center!important;
  }

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.img-legend{

margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
/* Responsive layout - makes the four columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column-legend-map {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height: 500px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="map1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `window.onload` function. I'd suggest looking into [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) they allow for more then one to be present, for your case a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) would do

Comment: Is it because you're replacing the content of `window.onload` twice? i.e. you're not saying to run both functions on load, you're saying to run the first one then changing your mind and saying to run the second one. Solution might be to create a new function for `window.onload` which calls both `loadScript();` and your other function.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, These 2 scripts were not created by me, I am new to javascript. Can you explain to me ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

your code : `var header = document.getElementById('header');`

but no element id = `header`

```js
//For google map


var latitudeCenter = "";
var longitudeCenter = "";
var lastOpenedInfoWindow = "";
var mapsGenerated = "";
var infoMap = [];
var zoneCoords = [];
var miniZoneCoords = [];
var trou = new Array();
var comp = 0;
var comp2 = 0;

var mapStyles = [
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
                "color": "#ffeb3b"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -35
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 35
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -55
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 30
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -90
            },
            {
                "lightness": 50
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 30
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -55
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -80
            },
            {
                "lightness": 25
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 25
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -65
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 75
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -25
            },
            {
                "lightness": 35
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -65
            },
            {
                "lightness": 40
            }
        ]
    }
];

function initialize() {

    for (var i = 0; i < mapsGenerated.length; i++) {
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            ajaxI: i,
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Branch/" + mapsGenerated[i][0] + "/AvailableCity?ReturnCitiesOfAssociatedBranches=true",
            contentType: 'application/xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            responseType: 'application/xml',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
            },

            success: function(xml) {

                i = this.ajaxI;
                comp++;

                jQuery(xml).find('BranchAvailableCityDTO').each(function() {
                    var branchIdXml = jQuery(this).find("BranchId").text();
                    var cityIdXml = jQuery(this).find("CityId").text();
                    if (mapsGenerated[i][1] == cityIdXml && mapsGenerated[i][0] == branchIdXml) {
                        latitudeCenter = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("CityCenterLocation").children().eq(0).text());
                        longitudeCenter = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("CityCenterLocation").children().eq(1).text());
                        infoMap.push({
                            id: i,
                            lat: latitudeCenter,
                            lng: longitudeCenter,
                            zoom: mapsGenerated[i][2],
                            branchId: mapsGenerated[i][0],
                            cityId: mapsGenerated[i][1]
                        });
                    }
                });

                if (comp == mapsGenerated.length) {

                    infoMap.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);
                    });

                    for (var i = 0; i < infoMap.length; i++) {
                        zoneCoords[i] = new Array();

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            ajaxI: i,
                            crossDomain: true,
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Zone?ZoneTypeId=1&BranchId=" + infoMap[i].branchId + "&CityId=" + infoMap[i].cityId + "&IncludeAssociatedCities=false",
                            contentType: 'application/xml',
                            dataType: 'xml',
                            responseType: 'application/xml',
                            headers: {
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
                            },
                            success: function(xml) {
                                i = this.ajaxI;
                                comp2++;
                                
                                jQuery(xml).find('ZoneDetailDTO').each(function(index) {
                                    
                                    zoneCoords[i][index] = new Array();
                                    
                                    if ( !( infoMap[i].cityId == 105 && index <= 1)  )  { 
                                        jQuery(this).find("Geometry").children("Coordinates").children("d4p1\\:ArrayOfDouble").each(function() {
                                            var latitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).children().eq(1).text());
                                            var longitude =  parseFloat(jQuery(this).children().eq(0).text());
                                            zoneCoords[i][index].push({
                                                index: index,
                                                id: i,
                                                city: infoMap[i].cityId,
                                                lat: latitude,
                                                lng: longitude
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                                

                                if (comp2 == infoMap.length) {
                                    
                                    infoMap.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0); });
    
                                    var maps = [];
                                    var infowindow = "";

                                    for (var i = 0; i < infoMap.length; i++) {

                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            ajaxI: i,
                                            crossDomain: true,
                                            type: 'GET',
                                            url: "https://restapifrontoffice.reservauto.net/api/v2/Station?" + infoMap[i].branchId + "&CityId=" + infoMap[i].cityId,
                                            contentType: 'application/xml',
                                            dataType: 'xml',
                                            responseType: 'application/xml',
                                            headers: {
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/xml',
                                            },
                                            success: function(xml) {
                                                comp2++;
                                                i = this.ajaxI;
                                                
                                                var point = infoMap[i];
                                                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
                                                
                                                var mapOptions = {
                                                    center: latlng,
                                                    zoom: point.zoom,
                                                    minZoom: 8,
                                                    maxZoom: 16,
                                                    zoomControl: true,
                                                    mapTypeControl: false,
                                                    scaleControl: false,
                                                    streetViewControl: false,
                                                    rotateControl: false,
                                                    fullscreenControl: false,
                                                    styles: mapStyles,
                                                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                                };

                                                maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + (i + 1)), mapOptions);
                                                
                                                if (zoneCoords[i].length) {
                                                    
                                                    for (var y = 0; y < zoneCoords[i].length; y++) {
                                                        miniZoneCoords[y] = new Array();
                                                        trou[y] = new Array();
                                                        for (var z = 0; z < zoneCoords[i][y].length; z++) { 
                                                            miniZoneCoords[y][z] = new google.maps.LatLng( zoneCoords[i][y][z].lat, zoneCoords[i][y][z].lng );
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    var Zones = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                        paths: miniZoneCoords,
                                                        strokeColor: "#228BE6",
                                                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                                        strokeWeight: 2,
                                                        fillColor: "#228BE6",
                                                        fillOpacity: 0.15,
                                                    });
                                                    
                                                    Zones.setMap(maps[i]);
                                                    
                                                }
                                                
                                                jQuery(xml).find('StationDTO').each(function() {
                                                    var name = jQuery(this).find("StationName").text();
                                                    var stationNumber = jQuery(this).find("StationNb").text();
                                                    var latitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("Location").children(":first").text());
                                                    var longitude = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("Location").children().eq(1).text());
                                                    
                                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                        position: {
                                                            lat: latitude,
                                                            lng: longitude
                                                        },
                                                        map: maps[i],
                                                        icon: "https://www.communauto.com/lib/img/MAP/icon_vert.png"
                                                    });

                                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                                                        return function() {
                                                            closeLastOpenedInfoWindow();
                                                            var nom = 'Station ' + stationNumber;
                                                            infowindow.setContent('<span style="color:#8dc63f; font-weight:bold;">' + nom + '</span><br><span style="color:#4A5866;">' + name + '</span>');
                                                            infowindow.open(maps[i], marker);
                                                            lastOpenedInfoWindow = infowindow;
                                                        }
                                                    })(marker, infowindow));

                                                    function closeLastOpenedInfoWindow() {
                                                        if (lastOpenedInfoWindow) {
                                                            lastOpenedInfoWindow.close();
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(maps[i], "idle", function() {
                                                        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
                                                    });

                                                });

                                                maps[i].setCenter(mapOptions.center);
                                            }

                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }

            }

        })

    }

}


function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    // id de la branche
    // id de la ville
    // zoom voulu
    mapsGenerated = [
        [4, 96, 12]
    ];

    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAt4c6dmsaJ9pPJi_xPk4qw_7BdHgV2YTE&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing&' + 'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;


//for random image background

window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var pictures = new Array('https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-3.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-2.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-paris-4.webp','https://paris.communauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/accueil-communauto-paris.webp');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
    }
}
```

```css
[id^=map] {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 0 1em; 
    width:100%; 
} 
[id^=map] a { 
  text-decoration:none;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column-legend-map {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center!important;
  }

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.img-legend{

margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
/* Responsive layout - makes the four columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column-legend-map {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header" style="width:100%; height: 500px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="map1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remove the API key in your code for security and privacy concerns. I noticed that you used the API key on the question.